# My app crashes because I declared a checkbox equal to a checkbox

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

When I open this activity my app crashes and says that it is due to this line of code:

```
private CheckBox chkWeekly = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_weekly);
```

The layout for alarm_details_repeat_weekly is right here:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/alarm_details_repeat_weekly"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/alarm_details_label_wednesday"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/alarm_details_label_wednesday"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:checked="true" />
```

Since some people asked, here is the logcat:

```
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2083)
        at minutemovement.mintemovement.com.minutemovement.AlarmDetailsActivity.<init>(AlarmDetailsActivity.java:28)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1083)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2312)
```

Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/EygRhAj4

Comment: Please post your logcat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. You declared your id as `alarm_details_repeat_wednesday` in your xml but then tried to get an object with id `alarm_details_repeat_weekly`. Change your code to this:

```
private CheckBox chkWeekly = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_wednesday);
```

Comment: I have a lot of checkboxes and grabbed the wrong one for the layout. I fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the private,

`CheckBox chkWeekly = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_weekly);` or declare the private CheckBox outside oncreate and initialize the object this way: `chkWeekly = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_weekly);`

Comment: I need to keep it private so I can access it from another class

Comment: You cant put all of that code in the oncreate, you should remove the "private CheckBox chkWeekly" and put it outside oncreate, after that you initialiize your "chkWeekly = (Che)......"

Comment: I've done that too but I'm still getting an error from the assignment

Comment: Looks like if you are calling the object before setContentView, can you take a print screen of you code? or just paste the code in pastebin?

Comment: Try with "requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);" instead "supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);"

Comment: I edited the original question to include a link to the pastebin

Comment: Is very hard try to fix this way because xml and some classes are missing, can you upload the project to git?